# Can I make a Rewrite Rule for this?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I don't know the `.htaccess` codes or the possibilities with it very well, maybe someone here can help me out if this is even possible before I try to program it.
We have a Wordpress Website with a Store Locator Plugin which by default creates a long URL with a location in it even when you deactivte the Location Service which we did.

The URL looks like this:

```
/shop-store/location=Rigistrasse%2055,%208006%20Z%C3%BCrich,%20Switzerland&radius=300
```

But because we don't use the Location Service, we also don't want such a long URL, so is it possible to hide everything expect from `/shop-store/` with a rewrite rule in the `.htaccess`? I thought this could be possible because you can also change or hide an URL with `.php` or `.html` in it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the REWRITE rules in place WordPress will continue to output the longer, location-based url. The .htaccess rules will only handle the request that comes into Apache. So the rule will be...

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop-store/*$ http://domain.tld/shop-store/ [R=301,L]`

But this will cause a 301 redirect for each click to your shop-store subfolder in WordPress. SEO gurus consider this a no-no.

I have not worked in WordPress for a while but there has to be a call being made to the StoreLocator Plugin that it injects the parameters on to the URL. If you can override that call and check if activated before adding the parameters then it would be the way to go.